# Nuxt client-side rendered DOM not matching server-rendered content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, element-ui

I'm trying to add plugins to this project:
https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt2-ssr-firebase

The plugins are rendered in the server but not on the client.

I've created a repository with a plugin for the Logo component.

Here's the source code:
https://github.com/infostatus/nuxt2-ssr-firebase-plugins-issue

Clone, then run "yarn setup" and "yarn dev".

The logo will show for a split second before error for not finding the component.

Comment: What is logo component supposed to do? Where is it located?

Comment: It just shows the logo image on the index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the problem.
It is the way deployment is being made.
It was not being copied correctly to the folders.

Fixed on the yarn deploy command.

Comment: Can I steal your answer to get bounty ? :D